# how can to stop timer task

Tags: android, timer, handler, timertask

I have a timer and timer task and handler and runnable
my code be execute every 10 seconds until ServerResponse variable in not empty and then redirect to another activity.

but when my code redirect to another activity timer task is working !!!!!

how can to stop timer task when we are in another activity??

```
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    new sendDataToServer().execute();
                    final Handler handler = new Handler();

                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if(serverResponse.length() > 0)
                            {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(PayementActivity.this,UserFormActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            }
                        }
                    }, 10000);
                }
            });
        }
    }, 0, 10000);
```

Comment: timer.cancel() should do the trick, before launching the Intent

Comment: Why are you using both a Timer and a Handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    new sendDataToServer().execute();
                    final Handler handler = new Handler();

                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if(serverResponse.length() > 0)
                            {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(PayementActivity.this,UserFormActivity.class);
                                if(timer!= null) {
                                timer.cancel();
                                timer.purge();
                                timer= null;
    }
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            }
                        }
                    }, 10000);
                }
            });
        }
    }, 0, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not answer your question directly, but just reactive extensions are a nice alternative to using TimerTasks. Check [this](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid) and [this](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) out.

```
subscription = Observable.interval(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())// Runs on a io thread pool
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) // Observes on UI thread 
                .subscribe(timeCount ->{
                    // Your code here
                 });
subscription.unsubscribe();// Stops the stream.
```